# Link Data to Visio Org Chart

Tags: excel, visio

I am trying to import data from Excel and then link it to the org chart in Visio 2016 so when I update the excel file then the org chart will update. The issue is I can only get Visio to link to excel if I import manually, however then I have to create the org chart one by one. If I use the org chart wizard I don't have to create it one by one but it will not link to the data in excel. Is there a solution I can use to get both?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create the diagramm with the org chart wizzard and make sure to have a unique id, then link to excel and use the id to automatically link to your shapes.

Comment: how do I make sure to have a unique ID? I am not asked at any point in the wizard to define a unique ID.

Comment: I have a unique ID in the excel sheet, how do I link it in Visio?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-link-imported-data-to-shapes-be56f5ff-9b13-4311-9a6c-b27dd243dbea https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Tips-and-tricks-for-linking-data-b5de55e0-7407-48cf-bf99-43d1c267c294